# Linked List in C Searching/Inserting

Tags: c, null, doubly-linked-list

I'm trying to write a code for emulating an MMU in a computer (kind of irrelevant), and after going through breakpoints in a debugger I've found that I'm having troubles with this linked list for searching and inserting.

If I don't include the line "table->first = NULL;" then I get an access violation error because it skips the function inside "if(table->first == NULL){" in my Insert function.

Also, when I try to do use my search function (after inserting one node into the list), the while loop goes through a second iteration (even though there shouldn't be anything that table->current points to) and then causes another access violation on the line "sum = table->current->end - table->current->start;"

Is there something with linked lists and the NULL value that I'm missing? I've also tried to change the while loop condition (in my search function) to "while(table->current)" and "while(table->current != 0)" and neither change made a difference. You can ignore all of the pthread parts, I have them commented out because I was debugging on a windows machine/haven't got to that part yet.

Thank you for any advice you can give!

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
//#include <pthread.h>

#define max_size 20

struct node //nodes for double linked list
{
  int start;
  int end;
  int free; //Tags for removal
  struct node *prev;
  struct node *next;
};

typedef struct node node;

typedef struct //double linked list struct for page table
{
  node *first;
  node *last;
  node *current;
  int is_available; //Determines whether or not enough space is available
} page_table;

//pthread_mutex_t mux;
page_table* table;

void Insert(node *old, node *newnode, int size);
void Remove(node *node);
node* Search(int size);
void tagRemove(int size);

int main()
{
  table = (page_table*) malloc(sizeof(page_table));
  table->first = NULL;
  table->last = NULL;
  node* node1 = (node*) malloc(sizeof(node));
  node* node2 = (node*) malloc(sizeof(node));
  node* node3 = (node*) malloc(sizeof(node));
  node* node4 = (node*) malloc(sizeof(node));
  Insert(NULL, node1, 2);
  node* temp = Search(3);
  //Insert(temp, node2, 3);
  //temp = Search(4);
  //Insert(temp, node3, 4);
}

void Insert(node *old, node *newnode, int size)
{
  if(table->first == NULL){
    table->first = newnode;
    table->last = newnode;
    newnode->start = 0;
  }
  else if(old->next == NULL){
    old->next = newnode;
    newnode->prev = old;
    table->last = newnode;
    newnode->start = old->end;
  }
  else if(old == table->first){
    newnode->next = table->first;
    table->first->prev = newnode;
    table->first = newnode;
    newnode->start = 0;
  }
  else{
    newnode->next = old->next;
    old->next = newnode;
    newnode->prev = old;
    newnode->start = old->end;
  }
  newnode->end = newnode->start + size;
  newnode->free = 0;
  table->current = newnode;
}

void Remove(node *node)
{

  if(node == table->first && node == table->last) {
    table->first = NULL;
    table->last = NULL;
  } else if(node == table->first) {
    table->first = node->next;
    table->first->prev = NULL;
  } else if (node == table->last) {
    table->last = node->prev;
    table->last->next = NULL;
  } else {
    node->next->prev = node->prev;
    node->prev->next = node->next;
  }
}

node* Search(int size){
  table->current = table->first;
  int temp_size;
  int sum = 0;
  while(table->current != NULL){
    temp_size = 0;
    sum = table->current->end - table->current->start;
    if(sum>=max_size)
      return NULL;
    temp_size = table->current->end - table->current->start;
    table->current = table->current->next;
    if(size<=temp_size)
      return table->current->prev;
  }
  return 0;
}

void tagRemove(int size)
{
  int sum;
  node* temp = table->first;
  sum = temp->end - temp->start;
  temp->free = 1;
  while(temp != NULL){
    temp = temp->next;
    sum += temp->end - temp->start;
    temp->free = 1;
    if(sum < size)
      return;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll save yourself a lot of trouble if you always use `calloc` instead of `malloc`.  `calloc` clears the memory it allocates to all zeroes, and `malloc` does not.  From a quick glance at your code, it looks like you expected all your allocated memory to be zeroed.

Case in point, `node1->next` and `node1->prev` are uninitialized but after you insert `node1` into your table you use them during your search.

Comment: Ah yes, that makes a lot of sense. I seemed to have confused myself with a linked list I made in C++ and the way I initialized those nodes. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

have you tried making

> ```
> node1->next=NULL
> Insert(NULL, node1, 2);
> node* temp = Search(3);
> ```

? does that gives the same error ?

Comment: If that were necessary (which I don't believe it is) then it would make my actual program impossible, because the actual overarching program doesn't always add nodes to the end of the list, it adds them to random parts of a list

Comment: no doubt... but whenever you create a new node make the next and the previous equal to NULL. These values should be adjusted in the insert function i.e whenever you would need to insert in between of nodes, adjust the next and previous pointer which means only change them when a change is required else let them remain NULL.

Comment: if calloc fixes the problem which in this case it seems possible. then the NULL is the reason of your errors. calloc would cause an overhead as the memory would be initialized to zero. As u r designing an MMU, u should be concerned about the performance as well.